# Extracting two columns and search for specific words in the first column remaining without cuting the ones remaining

Tags: linux, grep, cut

I have a .csv file filled with names of people, their group, the city they live in, and the day they are able to work, these 4 informations are separated with this ":".

For e.g

```
Dennis:GR1:Thursday:Paris
Charles:GR3:Monday:Levallois
Hugues:GR2:Friday:Ivry
Michel:GR2:Tuesday:Paris
Yann:GR1:Monday:Pantin
```

I'd like to cut the 2nd and the 3rd columns, and prints all the lines containing names ending with "s", but without cutting the 2nd column remaining.

For e.g, I would like to have something like that :

```
Dennis:Paris
Charles:Levallois
Hugues:Ivry
```

I tried to this with grep and cut, and but using cut ends with having just the 1st remaining.

I hope that I've been able to make myself understood !

Comment: Indeed, sorry. I've edited and my post and tried to make a little bit clearer.

Comment: Do we agree on the fact that A CSV file is a spreadsheet file containing data on each line separated by a separator character (usually a comma, semicolon, or tab) ? For me it is. In my case, the data is separated with a colon ":".

Comment: The file that has been given to me is a .csv file, that's why I'm saying it's a csv file, otherwise, I wouldn't have been saying it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1~/s$/{print $1, $4}' file
Dennis:Paris
Charles:Levallois
Hugues:Ivry
```

To address your comment requesting a grep+cut solution:

```
$ grep -E '^[^:]+s:' file | cut -d':' -f1,4
Dennis:Paris
Charles:Levallois
Hugues:Ivry
```

but awk is the right way to do this.

Comment: Works perfectly fine, however, it is possible to have the same output as the command you gave me, without awk. For e.g with grep, and cut.

Comment: OK I added that but awk is really the right tool for this kind of problem.

Comment: The grep command doesn't work for me, it prints a names not ending with a "s". Here's a part of the output
Thibault:Bagnolet
Frederic:Paris
Anais:Bagnolet
Nicolas:Levallois
Celine:Evry
Patrick:Paris
Bastian:Paris.6.
Cyril:Ivry

Comment: Then you copy/pasted the script incorrectly or your input file doesn't REALLY look like what you've posted. Don't try to post formatted text (e.g. code, input, or output) in a comment as you can't. That has to go in your question. The regexp in the grep command is extremely simple and clear though and it CANNOT output lines where the first :-separated field does not end in s.